# Using IO#pos and IO#seek with UDPSocket

Tags: sockets, dns, crystal-lang

I have a `UDPSocket` instance:

```
io = UDPSocket.new
io.connect "8.8.4.4", 53
```

It connects to a DNS server over port 53, sends a DNS query and retrieves the result. DNS has built-in message compression in the form of pointers, see [RFC 1035](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1035), 4.1.4. Message compression. Instead of a domain name, resource records can contain a message offset to point to the domain of the question. This is so the domain name doesn't have to be repeated for each record.

I have implemented this as follows in my resource record class:

```
 def self.from_io(io : IO, format : IO::ByteFormat) : self
    domain = ""
    loop do
      codepoint = UInt8.from_io io, format
      break if codepoint == 0
      if codepoint >= 192 # if the octet starts with 11 as defined in the rfc
        current_pos = io.pos
        pointer = UInt8.from_io io, format
        io.seek(pointer)
        # read the string...
      end
      # ...
    end
end
```

This does not work because `UDPSocket` does not implement `IO#pos` and `IO#seek`:

```
Unhandled exception: Unable to pos
```

To fix this, I have created a subclass that utilizes `IO::Memory`:

```
class DNS::DNSSocket < UDPSocket
  def initialize(family : Socket::Family = Socket::Family::INET)
    super family
    @memory = IO::Memory.new
  end

  def read(slice : Bytes)
    if slice.size + pos > @memory.size
      super slice
      @memory.write slice
    else
      @memory.read slice
    end
    slice.size
  end

  def pos
    @memory.pos
  end

  def pos=(value)
    @memory.pos = value
  end

  def seek(offset, whence : Seek = IO::Seek::Set)
    @memory.seek offset, whence
  end

  def clear
    @memory.clear
  end
end
```

My questions are as follows:

1. Is this a good solution, or do you know of something more elegant?
2. The `IO::Memory` instance needs to be reset after each message. Is it possible to call `clear` at the end or beginning of a datagram (packet) from within my DNSSocket implementation? I can also call it in my message parser but I'd prefer not to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UDP is a connectionless communication model and thus doesn't support streaming. `UDPSocket` inherits `IO`, but it shouldn't and I think that's actually a flaw in the API caused by `Socket` inheriting from `IO`. It still works, because the underlying syscalls used by the IO implementation also work with UDP sockets. But using a `UDPSocket` as an IO is not ideal and should be avoided. Since datagrams are usually short messages anyway, it's perfectly fine to load them entirely into memory.

So, I'd advise to use `UDPSocket#receive` instead, which allows you to easily wrap the slice in `IO::Memory`.

Answer (score 0):

To add to the other reply, the solution is much much simpler than I thought.

```
slice = Bytes.new(512)
socket.read slice
io = IO::Memory.new slice
```